# Pass constants to onclick listener in JS

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to pass constant arguments to `onclick` listener.
I know it's possible in HTML to do this :

```
<element onclick="myScript(453);">
```

But in JS I can't do this :

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    button = document.createElement('button');
    button.onclick = function () {
        myScript(i);
    };
}
```

This behavior is because `i` becomes undefined at end of loop or at least it is equal to `data.length`.
What I would like to do is instead of passing `i`, passing only the current value of it.

Comment: Use `let` instead of `var`. There are multiple duplicates that describe this problem. I'll try to find one.

Comment: @jabaa, amazing ! thank you for this quick answer :)